# Where do I post answers instead of questions?

Tags: support, questions, answers

I was wondering if Stack Overflow has a place that accepts tutorials or articles in general.

I like the whole feel of SO, so felt like asking this question.

Comment: You're thinking of Jeopardy.

Comment: Hilarious one, Nosredna.

Comment: Ok ok... I'm sorry... Didn't know about meta.stackoverflow.com! Pardon my ignorance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO isn't really designed for tutorials/articles, but if you've just discovered a neat way to do something and want to share that information, one option is to open a question then immediately answer it yourself.

Comment: Ah... I thought I would be busted for that! Thanks for the suggestion...

Comment: @Legend: some people think that is good manners that you make your *answer* community wiki. This behavior is not only allowed, but encouraged. The idea is to make Stack Overflow the biggest existing programming knowledge base.

Comment: I don't make my questions CW...I wants points!

Comment: @iftrue: Question is fine.  Just mark the answer that way.

Comment: @Joel, if that is to be officially encouraged, how about making self-answers always CW?

Answer (score 1):

Get a blog.  [Sha na na na, sha na na na na](http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/standbyme/getajob.htm)

Comment: Yeah actually you are right... But I'm not finding a blog provider that has a good support for programming languages... Do you know anyone? If I can't find anyone, then maybe I'll start putting everything down here at SO of course, in the form of questions :P